# Oracle SQL consuming entire 200G of temp space

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the underlying table that does not have an index and wanted to create a single index column based on  composite columns as below. However, when doing that the underlying query runs for ages and consumes entire temp space. How can we write this differently?

```
"select /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ a.* , a.id||a.period as d_idx from test1 a join test2 b on test1.id=test2.id where b.acct='Clnt'
```

The reason I’m doing this "a.id||a.period as d_idx" is because our logic needs a single index column (not composite), so I’m concatenating these and making a single index column.

```
Error report -
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on `test1.id`, `test2.id` and possibly `test1.acct`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any data from `test2` so I wonder why you're joining it into the query. If you're just using the INNER JOIN to limit the rows processed from `test1` then the following might be faster:

```
select a.* , a.id||a.period as d_idx
  from test1 a 
  where a.acct='Clnt' AND
        a.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TEST2)
```

I also suggest NOT including the PARALLEL hint until your query works, so that you can determine if PARALLEL(8) will be faster.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly the explain plan shows increased cost with this "IN" clause?? also it should be aact ='Clnt' coming from TEST2 table as we do not have it in Test1.. we r joining this Test2 table to filter for only clients

Comment: Although the cost may increase I suggest running the queries anyways and *see* which one runs faster. Cost != time. The only fields which might help by being indexed are TEST1.ID, TEST2.ID, and TEST1.ACCT. Also - I just copied the `a.acct='Clnt'` from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ... FROM)`
It is su much better use EXISTS clause.
You must play with alias and transform the content of select stmt into WHERE of EXISTS.

```
SELECT a.* , a.id || a.period as d_idx  
FROM test1 a 
WHERE a.acct='Clnt' AND
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEST2 b WHERE b.ID = a.ID);
```

You do not need DISTINCT, because that statement just check with the first one.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you The Where exits still same performance.. can u sight me a example as well

Comment: @stackuser Maybe you can do dbms_stats. Sometimes oracle gets a bad plain of execution because it not has information. Do F10 and if you find cartesian, put dbms_stats.